# Stored procedure CASE statement in WHERE clause taking parameter from Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, where-clause

I am using a stored procedure and SSRS.

My data has a column that has a binary value (1=Inside/2=Outside). And in the report the user has the parameter option to select Inside (1), Outside (2), or Both (3). In the where clause I used the following CASE statement, which works great for when inside or outside is selected but returns no data when both is selected.

```
WHERE 
    db.Location = CASE 
                      WHEN @loc = 1 THEN 1 
                      ELSE CASE 
                               WHEN @loc = 2 THEN 2 
                           END 
                  END
```

What can I use to be able to do the same as above, but add the ability to select both?

Comment: `where @loc = 3 or dbo.location = @loc`. Also, you seem to have misunderstood `case`, it's simpler than you think! You don't have to do `case when a then b else case when c then d end end`. You can just do `case when a then b when c then d end`

Comment: <pedantry> [`Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is an _expression_, not a _statement_, in T-SQL. </pedantry>

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a simple `OR`?

```sql
WHERE (db.Location = @loc OR @loc = 3)
```

Note that you may find you want to add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to your query with such a clause, as the plans for when `@loc` has a value of `3` may be different to if it has `1` or `2`.